# Pull request template for Bitbucket

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, pull-request

For github we have a great feature for pull requests that is explained here https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository/

and a good example is here

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md

Do we have something for Atlassian Bitbucket? If yes when did they start supporting this feature?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Bitbucket Cloud (BitBucket.org)

Such a feature *was not* supported, but now *is*! It's called Default Description, and it's [been available since Nov 2018](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11571/pull-request-description-templates#comment-49207099) if you use bitbucket.org.

You can access it in your repository's settings page.

[image]

#### Bitbucket Server

If you use your own instance of BitBucket, there's an equivalent feature in the works: [BSERV-8663](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-8663).

Comment: Thank you Brad, in what version did it start being supported?

Comment: @mCeviker, if you use bitbucket.org, it's [been available since Nov 2018](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11571/pull-request-description-templates#comment-49207099). If you use your own instance of BitBucket, the equivalent feature request for Bitbucket Server is [BSERV-8663](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-8663).

Comment: Seeing as the situation has changed, and if you found that I answered your original question, you might consider accepting this answer.

Comment: Does the default description allow for filling out a checklist interactively for each PR? It looks like it's a static piece of text, which is a little different from what GitHub offers.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, pull request template is not supported for Atlassian Bitbucket recently. And the feature has not been added in their roadmap so far.

More details, you can also refer the issue [Custom Pull Request Description Template (BB-14637)](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11571/custom-pull-request-description-template) and the post [Creating a template for pull request](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Creating-a-template-for-pull-request/qaq-p/765992).

Comment: @mCeviker, it may not concern you anymore, but Bitbucket does have a [pull request template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54488106/5432315), now.